# Unable to use launchpad.sh to install Websphere 7.0

Tags: websphere-7

I am in process of installing of the older version of Websphere AS on RHEL. WAS is version 7.0.

I am attempting to use launchpad.sh script however I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while starting the launchpad. This error typically occurs when 
the launchpad is unable to find a supported browser. Check your product's 
documentation for a list of supported browsers.
```

The procedure to fix this is as following for Mozilla

```
export BROWSER=/usr/bin/mozilla
```

Since I use Firefox instead of Mozilla. I have set Browser variable like this

```
export BROWSER=/usr/lib64/firefox
```

The funny part is that this is error pops up in Firefox. Any suggestions how to solve this issue?

As a side note I can install required products just using install script but I'd like to use a recommended approach.

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a product issue.  I recommend opening a PMR with IBM.

Comment: This might be too late as it is an older product.

Comment: WebSphere Application Server 7.0 is still supported by IBM.

Comment: Hi - WAS 7.x is fully supported.  FireFox is also "supported".  The problem is that Launcher relies on a DEPRECATED Firefox API.  WORKAROUNDS: 1) Install an OLDER version of FF (e.g. FF 10.2) or 2) don't use launchpad.sh.  Details are here: http://sometimessavvy.blogspot.com/2013/03/ibm-launchpad-will-not-start-unable-to.html

Answer (score 1):

Sigh. Since sometime in late 2012, IBM fixed launchpad to not fail for versions of FF up to 99, but it still fails for versions after 17. See [this TechNote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21631652/) for the fix.

Comment: Link is not working anymore. Please update! I found [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21643517) to be relevant and useful, but is obviously not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hello,
it happens quite often no matter which IBM technology / brand it is. It's caused by the fact, that you're using unsupported browser (a newer version perhaps) and you cannot go through the prerequisity check. The fact that the error message you get is displayed in Firefox means, that the launchpad can find the browser, but doesn't consider it to be supported, so opens, I guess, launchpad/nobrowser.sh which displays the statement.

There should be a file **launchpad/browser.sh** which should contain something like

```
supportedFirefoxVersion()
{
case "$*" in
 *Firefox\ [1-9].*) return 0;;
 *Firefox/[1-9].*) return 0;;
 *Firefox*) return 1;;
 *rv:1.[7-9]*) return 0;;
 *rv:[2-9].*) return 0;;
 *rv:*) return 1;;
 Mozilla*\ 1.[7-9]*) return 0;;
 Mozilla*\ [2-9].[0-9]*) return 0;;
 *) return 1;;
esac
}
```

Now, for Firefox **< 20** you simply add this line into the case
`*Firefox\ 1[0-9].*) return 0;;`

resp. for Firefox **> 20**
`*Firefox\ 2[0-9].*) return 0;;`

BTW there's nothing recommended on using the launchpad anyway :) (you can still use silent method.) Since WAS 8.5 I guess there's IBM Installation Manager, which is much bigger evil, than this launchpad, trust me :)

Comment: Since I have Firefox version 17 I have added the following line `*Firefox\ 1[0-9].*) return 0;;` .It still doesn't work :(

Comment: Have you added the line before `*Firefox*) return 1;;`? This is my browser.sh which worked just fine:  
`*Firefox\ [1-9].*) return 0;;`  
`*Firefox/[1-9].*) return 0;;`  
`*Firefox\ 1[0-9].*) return 0;;`  
`*Firefox*) return 1;;`

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the launchpad/browser.sh file or Download an old Firefox version .

Access a FTP from Mozilla and Install an older version. Can be Firefox 9
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/

export the variable BROWSER to your Firefox $PATH/firefox, and Run your lauchpad.sh